# Split a list of objects into sub-lists of contiguous elements using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple class `Item`:

```
public class Item
{
  public int Start { get; set;}
  public int Stop { get; set;}
}
```

Given a `List<Item>` I want to split this into multiple sublists of contiguous elements. e.g. a method

```
List<Item[]> GetContiguousSequences(Item[] items)
```

Each element of the returned list should be an array of `Item` such that `list[i].Stop == list[i+1].Start` for each element

e.g.

```
{[1,10], [10,11], [11,20], [25,30], [31,40], [40,45], [45,100]}
```

=>

```
{{[1,10], [10,11], [11,20]}, {[25,30]}, {[31,40],[40,45],[45,100]}}
```

Here is a simple (and not guaranteed bug-free) implementation that simply walks the input data looking for discontinuities:

```
List<Item[]> GetContiguousSequences(Item []items)
{
        var ret = new List<Item[]>();

        var i1 = 0;
        for(var i2=1;i2<items.Length;++i2)
        {
            //discontinuity
            if(items[i2-1].Stop != items[i2].Start)
            {
                var num = i2 - i1;
                ret.Add(items.Skip(i1).Take(num).ToArray());
                i1 = i2;
            }
        }
        //end of array
        ret.Add(items.Skip(i1).Take(items.Length-i1).ToArray());

        return ret;
}
```

It's not the most intuitive implementation and I wonder if there is a way to have a neater LINQ-based approach. I was looking at `Take` and `TakeWhile` thinking to find the indices where discontinuities occur but couldn't see an easy way to do this.

Is there a simple way to use `IEnumerable` LINQ algorithms to do this in a more descriptive (not necessarily performant) way?

I set of a simple test-case here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wrIa2J

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not sure this is much better than your original, but for the purpose of another solution the general process is

1. Use `Select` to project a list working out a grouping
2. Use `GroupBy` to group by the above
3. Use `Select` again to project the grouped items to an array of `Item`
4. Use `ToList` to project the result to a list

---

```
public static List<Item[]> GetContiguousSequences2(Item []items)
{
    var currIdx = 1;
    return items.Select( (item,index) =>  new {
            item = item,
            index = index == 0 || items[index-1].Stop == item.Start ? currIdx : ++currIdx
        })
        .GroupBy(x => x.index, x => x.item)
        .Select(x => x.ToArray())
        .ToList();      
}
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mBfHru

---

Another way is to do an aggregation using `Aggregate`. This means maintaining a final `Result` list and a `Curr` list where you can aggregate your sequences, adding them to the `Result` list as you find discontinuities. This method looks a little closer to your original

```
public static List<Item[]> GetContiguousSequences3(Item []items)
{
    var res = items.Aggregate(new {Result = new List<Item[]>(), Curr = new List<Item>()}, (agg, item) => {
            if(!agg.Curr.Any() || agg.Curr.Last().Stop == item.Start) {
                agg.Curr.Add(item);
            } else {
                agg.Result.Add(agg.Curr.ToArray());
                agg.Curr.Clear();   
                agg.Curr.Add(item);
            }
        return agg;
    });     
    res.Result.Add(res.Curr.ToArray()); // Remember to add the last group
    return res.Result;
}
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HL0VyJ

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `ContiguousSplit` as a *corutine*: let's loop over `source` and either add `item` into `current` range or return it and start a new one.

```
  private static IEnumerable<Item[]> ContiguousSplit(IEnumerable<Item> source) {
    List<Item> current = new List<Item>();

    foreach (var item in source) {
      if (current.Count > 0 && current[current.Count - 1].Stop != item.Start) {
        yield return current.ToArray();

        current.Clear();
      }

      current.Add(item);
    }  

    if (current.Count > 0)
      yield return current.ToArray();
  }
```

then if you want materialization

```
List<Item[]> GetContiguousSequences(Item []items) => ContiguousSplit(items).ToList();
```

Comment: So much simpler, why didnt I think of this one!

Comment: @Jamiec but this answer didn't use Linq. your answer is very simple `Select` then `GroupBy` and `Select`. Technically you write just two lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is okay. I don't think that LINQ adds any simplification or clarity in this situation. Here is a fast solution that I find intuitive:

```cs
static List<Item[]> GetContiguousSequences(Item[] items)
{
    var result = new List<Item[]>();
    int start = 0;
    while (start < items.Length) {
        int end = start + 1;
        while (end < items.Length && items[end].Start == items[end - 1].Stop) {
            end++;
        }

        int len = end - start;
        var a = new Item[len];
        Array.Copy(items, start, a, 0, len);
        result.Add(a);
        start = end;
    }
    return result;
}
```